# Visual Studio Class Diagram not showing relationships

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

When I define my class properties with out using fields (which was enabled with C# 3.0), class diagram is not showing my one to one/many relationships. Inheritance is visible in the diagram though..

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

When you right click on the field or property you can select show as association or show as collection association.

Comment: Any way to do this for all class diagram members? It's a little tedious to do that for all items in the diagram.

Comment: Unfortunately, power toys didn't work for me in VS 2012 Ultimate using the version from that blog.

Comment: @zcrar70 have you found a way to do that for all members?

Answer (score 66):

It's for people like me who do not find where is the menu item in 1 minute.[image]

Answer (score 8):

In Visual Studio 2013: right click the class, click **Add**, and select the desired relationship.

[image]

More information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657806.aspx

Comment: Does this exist in VS2017 anywhere? Asking for a friend :)

Comment: @KyleMit Unfortunately, UML Designer has been removed since VS2015. Class Diagram of VS2015 and onwards only supports generating diagrams from source code. More info: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/uml-designers-have-been-removed-layer-designer-now-supports-live-architectural-analysis/

Answer (score 3):

This combines with Visual Studio and does everything you want to do with Class diagrams.
http://modeling.codeplex.com/

Comment: Does it work for Visual Studio 2017? It seams to have stopped in VS 2010.

Comment: Does anyone knows a link to the .msi file? The above link is no longer contains .msi file.

Answer (score 1):

Since someone asked how to download files from old codeplex.com, I will briefly explain the steps below.

1. Access the link. In this case it is http://modeling.codeplex.com/.
2. Click "download archive" button to download the archive.
3. Open the downloaded zip file. ex) modeling.zip [File structure in the archive file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SIWG.png)
4. Navigate to "releases" folder if you are after the binary not the source.
5. Open the releaseList.json file to see the description and the actual name of each file. [Detailed info for each file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMYDH.png)
6. Find the one you want and get the folder Id, file Id and FileName from the releaseList.json.
7. Navigate to the folder matching the folder Id. ex) 2
8. Select the file matching the file Id and copy to some other place. Rename the file with FileName from the releaseList.json.
9. You can go from there.