# C# class diagram viewer? Incl. relationships like has-a and is-a

Tags: c#, windows, uml, class-diagram

I'd like a GUI tool that can display a diagram of a C# project, consisting of classes connected with is-a and has-a relationships, and lists of public & private members for each class.

The VS "class diagram tool" is pretty lacking. Hard to navigate, doesn't display has-a relationships, not grouped by namespaces, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate](http://www.olegsych.com/2010/01/uml-modeling-and-code-generation-in-visual-studio-2010/) supports UML and if you don't have Ultimate there are plugins like [SDE for Visual Studio](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/sde/vs/).

Edit: SDE supports [Instant Reverse](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/sde/vs/provides/codedbeng.jsp#instantreverseeng) engineering of an existing assembly into a UML diagram.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to create diagrams manually. I want them to be displayed automatically for existing code.

Comment: @Stefan SDE has a feature named "Instant Reverse" that can do that... check out this [link](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/sde/vs/provides/codedbeng.jsp#instantreverseeng)

Comment: Thanks. I also posted another way that I found.

Comment: Hmm, does SDE let me group classes by namespace for a more organized overview?

Comment: Yes, but it's a manual process. You'd have to either select all namespace members after Instant Reverse or build the diagram with all the members and manually group them into namespace groups later...

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to do it in VS. It's described in this answer:

[Visual Studio Class Diagram not showing relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708977/visual-studio-class-diagram-not-showing-relationships/708991#708991)

See the second comment, which recommends using PowerToys for the VS class designer. Works great.

Comment: Thanks for the useful link didn't know about PowerToys for the Class Designer.